If numerous people 'believe' that someone/something guides them through life, does it make it legitimate for philosophical discussion?

Metaphysics is a branch of philosophy that studies the fundamental
structure of reality, and how it influences life. It's often
considered to be more fundamental than other types of philosophical
inquiry, and is sometimes called "first philosophy". Metaphysics is
concerned with explaining the features of reality that exist beyond
the physical world and our immediate senses, and it often uses both
science and philosophy to answer its questions.

I understand that these kinds of questions are usually left for theologians to discuss.
But the recent entry of Simulation Theory into mainstream philosophy could possibly give a second (scientific) look at traditionally metaphysical philosophical questions?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Things like the scientific method, Popper's criteria, or philosophical methods don't really have a lot to say about how to 'correctly' come up with a hypothesis or question, and care more about the process of finding evidence to prove/disprove a claim. So in that sense, one is welcome to use personal belief to choose a hypothesis or question.
Plenty of philosophers (and scientists) have believed something because of a strong personal, unprovable intuition or feeling. Any Christian theologian writing about God presumably believed in God before they set about trying to logically prove his existence. For a "silly" example, this semi-tongue-in-cheek paper about modal realism talks about how in the end, the author came to believe, or at least enjoy imagining, his modal-realism-possible-world girlfriend.
I think the goal of the philosopher or scientist in this case is to recognize that "I feel it to be true" will not be sufficient proof to convince others who do not share that feeling (and indeed, is not particularly good evidence to base one's personal belief on). And thus they need to rely on other arguments that will convince people.
(As an example: one problem in metaphysics is the question of nonexistent objects. My intuition here is that nonexistent objects don't exist, and that it's silly to say 'X exists, but does not exist in the world'. A philosopher who thinks "nonexistent objects exist in some form" wouldn't get very far with "I feel they exist! I am feeling them existing right now". Instead, the usual response is something like: "What do you mean when you say 'Pegasus has wings'? Are you saying that Pegasus exists in the real world? or would it be equally correct to say 'Pegasus has no wings'?" By asking that, they're trying to show that their metaphysics is better at explaining a phenomenon that I also observe.)


You could argue that we are Avatars - for the ancient consciousness that made its way from future human consciousness to the digital format. But, as with any Avatar, you can be set adrift when your guide is busy or not interested. Then, automation takes charge.

So like, with this example, I do not share this feeling/belief and thus it's unconvincing to me. If someone wanted to convince me of the possibility or likelihood, they'd need to rely on:

investigating the distinction between 'avatar state' and 'automated state' and finding something that is measurable and aligns with this theory
finding experimental evidence of 'simulation-like' behaviour (some scientists have proposed looking for evidence of a preferred reference frame, which to the best of our knowledge doesn't exist. (e.g. if you built a house in minecraft it would look different when aligned with the game's XYZ block grid vs if you built it at an angle))
somehow arguing that living in a simulation (with this particular avatar setup) is far more likely than living in a mundane physical world.
etc, etc.

(I think, unsurprisingly, it would take a great deal of evidence to convince me. But the point is that this is the sort of evidence that it would take.)

"Kaia" - Thank you very much for your in-depth thoughts. I think you have touched correctly on the point that "proving" something in traditional philosophy, you need to make people to 'believe'.  As a byproduct of that, in philosophy, you need time to build your tribe of followers who are ready to 'believe' your theory. How beneficial is this tribal school of thought for real science?

@ScottRowe - You could argue that we are Avatars - for the ancient consciousness that made its way from future human consciousness to the digital format. But, as with any Avatar, you can be set adrift when your guide is busy or not interested. Then, automation takes charge.

@ScottRowe - If you don't 'believe' in something, it does not mean it does not have a legitimate chance to be true. And for Simulation Theory, it is probably the only thing in philosophy that has a chance to be practically and theoretically (science) proven, when people build their own simulator.

@NotThatGuy - Everything is understood in comparison. Can you compare Simulation Theory to some other philosophical theory that, in your eyes, is "More Proven"?

@D.Halsey - "What does simulation theory add to our understanding?" - For one, it would undermine traditional philosophy that can only thrive in hypothetical subjects that cannot be proven or disproved in scientifically accepted experiments. Simulation Theory - can prove itself scientifically by recreating at least a portion of our reality.
